# How to insert minor customization into Swagger UI inside its markup?

Tags: html, swagger-ui

I have a .NET Core project documented using Swashbuckle (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen 3.0.0 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUi 3.0.0). My aim's to add a custom tag right below the DIV with class *title* (i.e. below the service's name but above the endpoints).

When I investigate Swagger UI markup, I see there's a DIV with class *swagger-ui* and I'd like insert my stuff into it, so to speak. The setup I have today is a file called *donkey.html* which is being rendered when I access the URL of Swagger UI looking as follows.

```
...
<body>
  <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
  <div id="api_info"></div>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () { ... })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've googled for a few hours now and read a lot about OpenAPI and YAML among other things. However, the impression I'm getting is that it requires a whole rebuild of the Swagger UI project and my ambition targets a much simpler task at the moment.

Is there a way to jack the DIV called *api_info* so it renders as a part of *swagger_ui* with out regenerating the whole Swagger UI project?

I tried to augment onto the base layout as shown [here](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/customization/custom-layout/) but that ended poorly and turned out to be a bit more complicated than what I'm aiming for. Perhaps it's the only feasible approach to create a module, in which case I'll consider it, but that's the last resource in this case.

Comment: Do you use Swagger UI 3.x or 2.x? I mean the UI itself, not the .NET libraries; see [version detection](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md). If you are not sure, please add a screenshot of your Swagger UI and point where you want to insert extra stuff.

Comment: @Helen I can confirm it's the v3 I'm playing with (response object is *{"swaggerUi":{"version":"3.17.1","gitRevision":"g24faa46","gitDirty":true,"buildTimestamp":"Sat, 16 Jun 2018 07:51:13 GMT","machine":"travis-job-311a007d-ebec-4b3c-bc7e-58ad5df1e1d8"}}*). As for the placement of the DIV, I'd like the control with ID *#api_info* to be rendered right below or above the title (i.e. "*Swagger Petstore*" at the link you so kindly provided).

Comment: @Helen I forgot to mention that I tried augmenting the default layout, like in the edit to my question. However, that's about creating a plugin for Swagger, which seems to be a bit of overkill for such a small intrusion that I'm attempting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Swagger UI 3.x+ has the plugin system that lets you add or modify UI elements. Some documentation on plugins can be found at:
[Plugins](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/customization/plugin-api.md#wrap-components)
[What's the intended way of customizing SwaggerUI 3.x?](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3821#issuecomment-345393659)

and there are some examples here: [Plugin catalog](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5027#issuecomment-438745785).

There is no need to recompile Swagger UI to use plugins, you can actually define the plugins directly in the `index.html` page. To add or change UI elements, you need a plugin that uses `wrapComponents` and [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to build the desired DOM structure. (See also [React Without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html).)

For the custom plugins to have effect, they must be added to the `plugins` list in the `SwaggerUIBundle` constructor.

#### Example

Here is a sample plugin that adds custom `<h3>` headers above and below the API title:

```
// index.html

<script>
window.onload = function() {

  // Custom plugin that adds extra stuff
  const MyCustomPlugin = function() {
    return {
      wrapComponents: {
        // add text above InfoContainer - same effect as above title
        InfoContainer: (Original, { React }) => (props) => {
          return React.createElement("div", null,
            React.createElement("h3", null, "I'm above the InfoContainer"),
            React.createElement(Original, props)
          )
        },

        // and/or add text above API description
        InfoUrl: (Original, { React }) => (props) => {
          return React.createElement("div", null,
            React.createElement(Original, props),
            React.createElement("h3", null, "I'm above the API description")
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }


  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    ...
    plugins: [
      MyCustomPlugin,       // <------ add your custom plugin here
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    ...
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Swagger UI with customized layour]