# How to display curl command in Swagger?

Tags: swagger-ui

I am using Swagger UI 3.24.2 and I want the curl statement to always show up in the UI. Currently, it shows up only when I click on the 'Try it out' button. Is there a straight forward way of achieving this behavior? I believe in the 2.0 version this behavior was enabled by default.

Thanks!

Comment: Adding more context: I am planning to use 'supportedSubmitMethods:[]', hence the 'Try it out' button will not be available to the user.

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Swagger UI - Add curl example with the "try it out" button disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016515/swagger-ui-add-curl-example-with-the-try-it-out-button-disabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the curl statement to *always* show up in the UI.

This is currently not supported, but there's a feature request:
[Add option to generate CURL in summary if OpenAPI definition has examples](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/8050).

Currently, Swagger UI generates the cURL command with the specific parameter values that the user entered, that's why cURL is only available *after* "try it out".

> I believe in the 2.0 version this behavior was enabled by default.

No, this behavior is the same in v. 2.x and 3.x

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if it's possible to get curl shown before 'Try it Out' if example values are provided for all fields?

Comment: @Tyeth not out of the box, but you can try writing a [plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815260/113116) for that.