# Swagger UI: Angular: download API via link

Tags: angular, swagger, keycloak, swagger-ui

I've added SwaggerUI component to my Angular app with the following configuration:

```
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        domNode: '#swagger-ui',
        url: <some.url.here>,
        requestInterceptor: async (request: HttpRequest<any>) => {
          const token = this.keycloakService.getToken();
          request.headers.Authorization = 'bearer ' + token;
          return request;
        }
      });
```

As you can see, I'm using `requestInterceptor` to add keycloak auth token to my request. Interceptor works fine with the main request (i.e. request for the API file).

But there is a link below the API title:
[image]

When I click to the link `/some/url/here` , `requesInterceptor` is not invoked. What should I add (property, plugin or preset) to the configuration to make it work ?

Comment: [`requestInterceptor`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#user-content-requestinterceptor) only applies to the initial spec load request (triggered by the `url` parameter in config), "try it out" and OAuth requests. It doesn't apply to the links in the info section and in descriptions (i.e. the regular links that you can right-click).

Comment: (cont.) That specific link is rendered by the [`InfoUrl`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/components/info.jsx#L83-L97) component. You can try overriding that component using a plugin to attach custom logic. [Here's a sample plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815260/113116) that modifies `InfoUrl`, maybe this will give you some ideas.