# How to override description 'No parameters' in Swagger for .Net Core Web Api?

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

In .Net Core Web Api project I have Get which doesn't need request data to be passed on. By default SwaggerUi generates 'No parameters' description under Parameters tab. See below.

[image]

My aim is to replace 'No parameters' string with something else. I'd like to add additional information why there is no need for parameters. If it's possible, then please share a knowledge.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775462

Comment: What you mean is that you want to customize the content you need to modify in the Parameters module in the request API without passing parameters?

Comment: The API doesn't contain any FromQuery or FromRoute parameters. It's parameter-less, therefore swagger shows up 'No Parameters' message on UI. Yes, I want to customize that message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven’t found a way to modify the custom content of parameters after searching for a long time, but you can add the remarks you need on the url, like this:

For enabling XML comments, we need to do the following steps:

1.In the Build tab of the project properties, check the box labeled XML documentation file. Let’s keep the auto-generated file path.

2.Suppress warning 1591, which will now give warnings about any method, class, or field that doesn’t have triple-slash comments.

[image]

In the ConfigureServices() method, configure Swagger to use the XML file that’s generated in the above step:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
       //......TODO

// Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
```

Now, adding triple-slash comments to the action method enhances the Swagger UI by adding a description to the section header.

```
 /// <summary>
        /// This is test    
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        /// 
       [Route("test")]
       [HttpGet]
        public string Test()
        {
            return "v1 test";
        }
```

Result:

[image]