# How to add custom warning before executing a request in Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring `@RestController` and a Swagger dependency. Is it possible to add a warning before executing a certain request in the Swagger UI?

I want the warning message to be popped-up when a user clicks on the `execute` button of a certain request.

[image]

Comment: What kind of warning? You'll probably need to write a [plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/customization/plugin-api.md) for Swagger UI and somehow include this plugin into the Swagger UI instance included in your app. Check out the [sample](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5027#issuecomment-438745785) [plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815260/113116) to get an idea of how to get started.