# How to add the customised text in swagger ui after clicking on the copy button

Tags: reactjs, swagger, copy, swagger-ui, clipboard

I want the copied text.. I'm using the swagger-ui package in react project... Customisation is possible in swagger? Do I need to use any other package like copy-to-clipboard with customised text.Pleasw let me how can I do that customisation.

thank you in advance..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In swagger ui copy button is not indicating the text was copied or not(after clicking on the the copy button it's not showing the text was copied or not) .. here i want the customised text like "copied" hope this helps... Let me now need more info

Comment: Minor Swagger UI customizations are possible using plugins [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815260/113116). Looks like you'll need to override/extend the [CopyToClipboardBtn](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/components/copy-to-clipboard-btn.jsx#L10) component.

Comment: I didn't get it can you explain again